# How to hide the database name in a php file

Tags: php, mysql

My database name is **student**, my problem is every time I include the database name in php file, using **include('student.php');**  the student.php file connect the mysql query statement.**This is normal**, but I want to hide the database name any where or other person doesn't  see the database and the database settings.

Comment: Have you tried using `DEFINE(DBNAME, "db_name");` in a separate include file?  Generally if they have access to the server, they'll find it.

Comment: You'd still be able to echo it etc...

Comment: I didn't know if this was for code viewing/demonstration purposes or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the correct answer, but how we usually do this in Rails is by setting the database settings as environment variables on the server (and locally) and have our app use these environment variables to configure that database connection. You could do the same thing in your PHP app to hide the db name (and password) from people editing the code and from source control. It also helps for deploying to multiple servers.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution you can do is set up your database with a mirror with a user which only has permission to do normal stuff, but not access or drop databases.

That way it doesn't matter what your students do or see the database as.

Comment: example code is:  dbconn.php   <?php $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_selectdb("student",$con);?>  this is for dbconn.php file and i include any other php file database connection using including('dbconn.php');.  But i want does not using this things of coding.i only using php coding in mysql the database automatically get.

Comment: First comment... ***DONT EVER LOG IN AS ROOT IN CODE!*** If there is any avenue of an exploit in your code the entirety of your database and possibly server is at the mercy of the hacker.

Create a new user account in the SQL server and allow it only the basic rights to the student database.
Then make the mysqli connection to the database with the user account. ***NOT ROOT! NEVER!*** Root should ***ONLY*** be used when logging in to phpmyadmin or other database management software to administer the database.

Comment: Suggested reading: http://php.net/manual/it/book.mysqli.php Mysql_ methods are being stopped/phased out/depricated because of Mysqli
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html how to create an user.